# Runtime detection of LDREX/STREX availability on Linux/ARM

Tags: c, linux, arm, atomic

Is there any reliable (preferably, free of both false negatives and false positives) way to detect availability of the `LDREX`/`STREX` atomic operations at runtime on Linux/ARM? I've looked for something in the `AT_HWCAP` field of the aux vector and found a few things which might indirectly imply availability (e.g. `HWCAP_LPAE` supposedly does) but they would likely have false negatives.

Comment: there are usually a zillion coprocessor registers with all kinds of this or that instruction supported or not flags.

Comment: Are they accessible by non-privileged code?

Comment: good question.  you may have to have your bootloader read or figure out whatever everything else needs to know then leave or provide that info to everyone else in every mode.

Comment: LDREX/STREX are for sharing ram across multiple cores can you detect if you have a multi-core processor in the non-priveledged code?

Comment: They're needed even for single-core since the kernel scheduler can interrupt the process between a load and subsequent store. Presumably the kernel invalidates the `LDREX` state at context-switch time so that, when the process is resumed, the `STREX` will fail and force a retry. So, checking for multi-core is useless.

Comment: Isn't LDREX/STREX an ARMv6 thing? Can't you just rely on architecture version? I believe this is what all Linux code relies on. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/atomic.h#L33

Comment: the arm documentation quite clearly states that chip designers are not required to support exclusive access (ldrex/strex) for uniprocessor designs.  meaning single core implementations of multi core capable cores.  ldrex/strex are strictly for sharing between cores, that is the purpose of those instructions.  If you only have one core then you really arent using them as they were intended (and depending on the implementation it is dumb luck if it works, if you go outside the caches then depending on the implementation, can have the loop hang).

Comment: as with many things arm the linux kernel improperly uses ldrex/strex

Comment: @dwelch: Well what is the intended way to implement atomics on arm? Is the intent that there's no way to do it at all except on multi-core machines??

Comment: By the way, what does "not support" mean? If `ldrex` and `strex` fault on uniprocessor machines, the kernel can just take care of them (albeit at an extreme performance cost). But if "not support" means "silently behave like normal load/store" that's a big problem and I don't see how such a machine is remotely usable...

Comment: The need for an atomic means you have more than one thing competing for one resource in a way that their memory cycles can overlap.  What is it that you are competing for that you cant do in a single atomic cycle?  128 bit quantities?

Comment: Look at how linux and others use ldrex/strex, they use them in an infinite loop waiting for the pair to have an exclusive access if the logic never returns exokay then you will never get that exclusive access and the kernel hangs.  at least the last time I looked but it has been a bit since I dealt with this.

Comment: @dwelch: Compare-and-swap. ARM does not have any single instruction for compare-and-swap; you have to construct it with `ldrex`/`strex`. Regarding the "infinite loop", this does not happen in practice. In any case the issue applies to all broken RISC archs that use ll/sc-style reservations rather than true atomic operations like x86 has.

Comment: traditional locking of a shared resource managed by a kernel driver has been around since the dark ages, platform independent.  This is a new feature and instruction pair to the arm world (relatively) not the only solution.  My understanding is the exokay comes back if there is no access from some other core between the accesses, which means it is no more atomic than just a load and store

Comment: The reason why I know so much about ldrex/strex is because we exactly did that, followed the arm docs, did not implement an exclusive access return, and hung linux in an infinite loop.  we correctly modified the linux sources (as with many other patches to fix arm brokenness that continues to plague linux) to use the SWP instruction.

Comment: I am not asking about implementing drivers or anything in kernelspace. This is a userspace question. I'm sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: if you cannot implement something in userspace to prevent other parts of userspace stomping on a shared resource (something you need atomic access to) and cannot then you need to have a single manager of that resource, a kernel driver.

Comment: my understanding of ldrex/strex would not grant you atomic access to something from a single core.  I guess I/we have to go re-read the rules about exclusive access operations.

Comment: On every other RISC architecture based on instructions like ldrex/strex, they're perfectly usable on a single core. The context switch simply resets the state from the ldrex-like instruction so that the strex-like instruction will fail.

Comment: The basic process for an exclusive access is:
1. A master performs an exclusive read from an address location.
2. At some later time, the master attempts to complete the exclusive operation by performing an exclusive write to the same address location. 3. The exclusive write access of the master is signalled as: • Successful if no other master has written to that location between the read and write accesses. • Failed if another master has written to that location between the read and write accesses. In this case the address location is not updated.

Comment: So from that text it is only detecting if some other master (core) has accessed between the ldrex/strex doesnt protect from the same core.

Comment: At least in practice (and this is how it works on all other similar archs) it will also fail if the *same* core has executed a `ldrex` for a different address before the `strex`. Thus, you just put an otherwise-useless `ldrex`/`strex` pair in the kernel context switch code, and thereby make sure any code that was preempted fails on the subsequent `strex`.

Comment: Uniprocessor systems are only required to support the non-shared memory model, allowing them to support
synchronization primitives with the minimum amount of hardware overhead.

Comment: @dwelch: So far what you've said is that they don't support synchronization primitives. Make up your mind...

Comment: That was cutting and pasting from the arm docs...ARM did a pretty bad job of handling exclusive access.  Telling the hardware folks one thing and software folks another and not really having a good system wide picture.  The picture I am trying to paint for you is that I dont believe that LDREX/STREX is completely useful for a single processor (with or without support outside arms IP).  At the end of the day success or fail comes down to the individual chip customers implementation, which is a much much longer conversation, since it is not limited to arm...

Comment: So simply detecting an armv6 or armv7 is not enough IMO...Now they claim that swp is deprecated, but at the same time they say you dont have to implement exokay, so which is it, what do you do if you dont have exokay and are trying to avoid swp?  I have not seen an answer...

Comment: @dwelch Where do they say you don't have to implement exclusive access stuff? Thing about ARMv6, it introduces a new memory model, so I don't see how you can get a way without implementing it. Also this is a nice read http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.genc007826/index.html

Comment: Uniprocessor systems are only required to support the non-shared memory model, allowing them to support synchronization primitives with the minimum amount of hardware overhead.

Answer (score 4):

`LDREX`/`STREX` were introduced in the ARMv6 architecture, so you just need to check the architecture version  - if it's v6 or later, you have them. If not, you don't. From privileged code you could read the MIDR directly, otherwise some userspace interface like `/proc/cpuinfo`.

If you really need to implement atomics that work across all architecture versions, you may be better off relying on the `cmpxchg` provided by the [Kernel User helpers](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/arm/kernel_user_helpers.txt?a=arm) than trying to roll your own.

Comment: At present I **am** relying on the kernel user helpers, but I've received complaints from some users with hardened kernels that have turned off `CONFIG_KUSER_HELPERS` and want direct use of the atomics. So perhaps my question is an instance of the so-called XY problem; I really should have asked: "How can I determine at runtime whether I should use kuser helpers or directly use atomics?"

Comment: If you are ARMv6+, use `STREX/LDREX`.  If you are ARMv5 (or less), you need to probe the *KUSER_HELPERS*.  As per the link, install a `SIGSEGV` and test `__kuser_helper_version` for a value larger than 2.  If you get a *SEGV* or the version is less than 2 **AND** you are ARMv5 (or less), you can not do lock-free with that kernel.  Give up as your users ask you to do the impossible.  Use `/proc/cpuinfo` as some chip vendors screw up *cp15* registers and the kernel will provide a work around (maybe a hard config).

Answer (score 0):

Mpcore, the TRM doesnt say if you can or cant access this in a non-priveledged mode.

```
MRC p15,0,<Rd>,c0,c0,0; reads Main ID register
```

The cpu id register a few after that does explicitly say: accessible in privileged modes only
So I would hope/assume the arm docs would have said the same thing about the main id register.  of course how many main id register answers do you have to wade through to verify what core this is or not?

Ahh, MIDR = Main ID Register, Notlikethat mentioned MIDR, I guess it is an easy test to see if you can access the MIDR in user mode...

EDIT:

The 1176 does clearly state about the MIDR.

> accessible in privileged modes only.

I wonder if that restriction went away.

EDIT2:

Verified on an mpcore, that you cannot access the MIDR in user mode.

EDIT3:

I think you have to rely on the kernel to help out userspace.  And/or if you only support ARMv6 or newer then ldrex/strex will be there and you dont have to check, assuming this is not running on a cortex-m, but an arm11 or cortex-a/r.